# Jhipster app logging to remote ELK (elastic stack)

Tags: logstash, jhipster, elastic-stack

I've been asked to configure an ELK stack, in order to manage log from several applications of a certain client. I have the given stack hosted and working at a redhat 7 server (followed [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/06/07/how-to-install-elastic-stack-elk-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel/) cookbook), and a test instance in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 (followed [this other](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) cookbook), but I've hit a roadblock and cannot seem to get through it. Kibana is rather new for me and maybe I don't fully understand the way it works. In addition, the most important application of the client is a JHipster managed application, another tool I am not familiarized.

Up until now, all I've found about jhipster and logstash tells me to [install the full ELK stack using Docker](https://jhipster.github.io/monitoring/) (which I haven't, and would rather avoid in orther to keep the configuration I've already made), so that Kibana deployed through that method already has configured a dashboard tunned for displaying the information that the application will send with the native configuration, activated in the application.yml `logstash: enabled: true`.

So... my questions would be... Can I get that preconfigured jhipster dashboard imported in my preexistent Kibana deploy. Where is the data, logged by the application, stored? can I expect a given humanly readable format? Is there any other way of testing the configuration is working, since I don't have any traffic going through the test instance into the VM?

Since that JHipster app is not the only one I care for, I want other dashboards and inputs to be displayed from other applications, most probably using file beat.

Any reference to useful information is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Take a look at this repository: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-console/tree/master/jhipster-console

there are the exports (in JSON format) from kibana stored in the repository, along with the `load.sh`

The scripts adds the configuration by adding them via the API. As you can imply, any recent dashboard is not affected by this, so you can use your existing configuration.